# File have not right posistion, after delete item from array using *ngFor, Angular, copy for next element, why?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

I have a huge form. And I have array of items, I display it with *ngFor, with trackBy, for remove/add for current index. BUT. On this item I have file, and when I remove some item from array my file have not right item, not right position, he copies for next, how I can solve it?

```
Component (remove method): 

    public onRemoveDirector(indexOfDirector: number): void {
        if (this.directors.length === 2) {
            this.showRemoveDirector = false;
        }
        this.directors.splice(indexOfDirector, 1);
        this.fileSelectedDirectors.splice(indexOfDirector, 1);
    }

HTML: 


    <div class="form-group clearfix" 
                 *ngFor="let director of directors; trackBy:identify ;let i = index;">
                 <div class="director-wrap" *ngIf="director">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3 class="col-sm-12 control-label user-form__second-title">{{"Person" | translate}} {{i+1}} *</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 file-label control-label">{{"Copy of identification document" | translate}}</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9 form-group clearfix">
                            <input type="file" 
                                class="personIdFile"
                                name="directorIdFileDirector_{{i}}"
                                (change)="onChangeDirectors($event, i)"/>
                            <div *ngIf="fileSelectedDirectors[i] || showFileValidation"
                                [hidden]="fileSelectedDirectors[i] || !showFileValidation"
                                class="alert alert-danger customer-error-messages alert-form-errors"
                                [ngClass]="{'hide-file': fileSelectedDirectors[i]}">
                                <div [hidden]="fileSelectedDirectors[i] || !showFileValidation">
                                    {{"The field is required" | translate}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to call `.splice()` on a `FileList` instance?

Comment: for copy my array of files?

Comment: `.files` property of `<input type="file">` element does not have a `.splice()` method

Comment: ok, I need to push my files for array, and copy it?

Comment: Yes. You can call `.splice()` on an instance of an `Array`